# JToken Getting the Value of Property With Specific Prefix

Tags: c#, json

I might be a simple question but I'm trying to access some specific key value pair from a JToken. This JToken is all key value pair as well. For example:

```
{
    "name": "Someone",
    "UTC": "2028-01-20T13:32:26",
    "localtime": "2028-01-20T12:32:14",
    "CUSTOM.datastoreversion": "70",
    "CUSTOM.swversion": "1804201116",
    "CUSTOM.apiversion": "1.25.0"
}
```

Some property contains a prefix "CUSTOM.", is there any way to filter out these elements in the JToken so I can only look at those properties and values instead?
I wanted to deserialise this part of data into a List and also add the mode for CustomizedData

```
public class CustomizedData
{
/// <summary>
/// Property Name
/// </summary>
public string PropertyName { get; set; }

/// <summary>
/// Property Value
/// </summary>
public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Update:

1. I don't intend to modify the original jtoken data.
2. I only want to figure out how to get property names and values from jtoken data.

Comment: Do you need the JToken to stay as a JToken or can it be converted to a JObject?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary it's okay to be converted to a Jobject, but i would love to learn if it's possible to get the data if we keep it as JToken as well.

Comment: Would you like to modify the object to exclude anything without "CUSTOM." or just want the property names(or/and values?)?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Thank you for following up - I should have been more clear in my question. But no, I just want to simply get the property names and corresponding values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a way but as you have an object, you first **must convert the `JToken` to a `JObject` to process it**.

This is because there's no concept of key-value pairs in a `JToken`.

A `JToken` is the base class for many other types like `JArray` (for arrays) and `JValue` (for strings, numbers, booleans etc.) to name a few. As such, a `JToken` just purely represents a [JSON token](https://www.json.org/json-en.html).

Therefore, it is impossible to process a `JToken`'s data in a meaningful way without casting it to the appropriate subclass.

As we have an object, we must cast the JToken to a `JObject`, which will still let us pass a 'JObject' to any method which needs a 'JToken' (as a 'JObject' inherits from a 'JToken').

After we have a `JObject`, we can then loop over the JSON object's keys and values as it implements [`IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, JToken>>`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm).

Looping over the keys, we then check to see if there are any keys that don't start with *CONTAINS.*

If such key(s) exists, we remove the property entirely based on the key name, from a deep clone copy.

We have to use a copy as in general, we cannot modify a collection & enumerate over it at the same time (*or it'll throw a `System.InvalidOperationException: 'Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.'`*).

We can then ultimately use the filtered `JObject` with properties starting with your desired prefix, loop over the keys and values & then create a `List<CustomizedData>`.

*You could also just do that on the first loop however for the sake of reusable code, I've opted to create an extension method.*

The below should work:

```cs
JToken testData = ...

var jObject = (JObject)testData;
var filteredJObject = jObject.FilterJObjectToPropertiesWithPrefix("CUSTOM.");

var customizedDataList = new List<CustomizedData>();

foreach (var obj in filteredJObject) {

  string name = obj.Key;
  JToken value = obj.Value;

  var customizedData = new CustomizedData {
    PropertyName = name,
    Value = value.ToString()
  };
  
  customizedDataList.Add(customizedData);
}
...
```

`JObjectExtensions.cs`

```cs
public static class JObjectExtensions
    {
        public static JObject FilterJObjectToPropertiesWithPrefix(this JObject source, string prefix)
        {
            var jObject = source;

            var jObjectCopy = (JObject)jObject.DeepClone();

            foreach (var obj in jObject)
            {
                if (!obj.Key.StartsWith(prefix))
                    jObjectCopy.Remove(key);
            }

            return jObjectCopy;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Ermiya, can you actually introduce a bit more, like: if I have filtered out those unwanted elements, how do I iterate through those elements?       I have a different data object that needs data populated from jtoken

Comment: The wanted ones.    I'm trying to get their value, yes.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but I don't think it helps either - The input is fixed and has to be type of Jtoken and I have no control over it. I tried your method above but there would be casting problems

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237847/discussion-between-weilun-yuan-and-ermiya-eskandary).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json).ToList(); 

  var customs=list.Where(j => j.Key.StartsWith("CUSTOM."));
  //or
 var customs=list.Where(j => j.Key.Contains("CUSTOM."));
```

customs

```
    CUSTOM.datastoreversion 70
    CUSTOM.swversion    1804201116
    CUSTOM.apiversion   1.25.0
```

how to use (example)

```
var customsData= list.Where(j => j.Key.Contains("CUSTOM.data"))
.Select(j =>j.Value ).FirstOrDefault();
```

output

```
70
```